# Python: Using derived class attributes in base class

Tags: python, inheritance

I was reading through some code when I came across this particular code where the base class method is printing some attributes which are from derived class, the object which is calling the method is from derived.

```
class A(object):
  def printFreak(self):
    print self.derived_attrib

class B(A):
  def __init__(self, num):
    self.derived_attrib = num

my_obj = B(10)
my_obj.printFreak()
```

Since I had not seen such behaviour before(like in C++), I am unable to understand this.

Can anyone help me understand this, how this works ? Can this be related to some concept of C++ ?

Comment: In Python, attributes are resolved at run-time, so it simply looks for an attribute called `derived_attrib` in the object referred to by `self`, and finds that there is one. It would work in C++ as long as `derived_attrib` was declared as field of `A` and then assigned in `B`, because then the compiler would be able to figure out what `self.derived_attrib` meant in `A`'s method.

Comment: C++ uses a strict memory layout, python uses a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. And it's ok/legal to use such pattern or is it considered a misuse ?

Comment: @mittal It's not a great idea for a parent class to make assumptions about its child classes like that. It'd be better if the `printFreak` method were an attribute of the child class that defines `.derived_attrib`. In Python, it's quite common for attributes to be added dynamically to class instances, but it's still a bit smelly for a method to make assumptions about attributes that aren't part of the class definition (either in the class itself or defined in one of its parents).

Comment: @khelwood Would you mind posting your comment as an answer? I think this can be removed from the "unanswered" list.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Certainly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, attributes are resolved at run-time, so it simply looks for an attribute called `derived_attrib` in the object referred to by `self`, and finds that there is one.

It would work in C++ as long as `derived_attrib` was declared as field of `A` and then assigned in `B`, because then the compiler would be able to figure out what `self.derived_attrib` meant in `A`'s method.